# Landau Levels and Magnetic length

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

I am looking into Landau Levels and keep coming across a magnetic length defined as follows for a 2D system:

$l_B=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar c}{e B}}$

I have seen numerous sources say this is:

$l_B\approx 26nm \sqrt{B[Tesla]} $

But by plugging those numbers in I don't see how this is the case - the units are just plain wrong. The thing is, I cannot for the life of me figure out what type of theorist units they used to 1) get this expression in the first place, and 2) calculate it for something realistic. The only hint I have is that it was done in the "Landau Gauge" - googling this yields nothing useful.

What units are being used, and how did they calculate this number?

Comment: I think this is a formula for a quick estimate: If you enter the number of the magnetic field strenght given in Tesla, you just have to take the square root of it and multiply it with 26 nm. The units are just nm.

Comment: I understand that. But it supposedly follows from the previous equation. Which doesn't yield that relationship.

Comment: There's no $c$ in the radical: $l_B = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{e B}}$ source: http://www.bourbaphy.fr/doucotpasquier.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first formula $l_B = \sqrt{\frac{ℏc}{eB}}$ , all constants are in CGS units and $B$ is in Tesla.

Constants in CGS-

$\hbar=1.05457266 *10^{-27}$ ergs s

$c=3*10^{10}$ cm/s

$e=4.8032068*10^{-10}$     esu

and

$1$ Tesla (SI)= $1*10^4$ G (CGS)

You will get the second formula.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the dimension is wrong. $[\hbar] = J\cdot s$, $[e] = A\cdot s$, where $J=$joule, $s=$second and $A=$ampere. Then, $[\hbar/e]=Wb=T\cdot m^2$, with $T=$tesla and $m=$meter. The light speed $c$ is erroneous [see this wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_flux_quantum]. Now you plug $\hbar\approx 10^{-34}J\cdot s$ and $e\approx 1.6\cdot 10^{-19}A\cdot s$ and you get $l_B\approx \sqrt{1000/1.6}\cdot nm/\sqrt{B[tesla]}\approx 25 nm~/\sqrt{B[tesla]}$.

Comment: The discrepancy in the appearance of $c$ is due to units.