# Landau levels degeneration measurement units

Tags: statistical-mechanics, quantum-statistics

I am still studying statistical mechanics. In the discussion on the Landau Diamagnetism, on various textbooks (I use the [Pathria](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123821886)), notes taken during lessons and on-line resources, I found several calculations showing that the degeneration of the Landau levels is:
$$g=L_xL_y \left( \frac{eB}{h c} \right) \, .$$
I think (a this point I'm not sure) that the measurement units for this quantity are $\frac{s}{m}$, which is plain wrong.

As answered in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110276/landau-levels-and-magnetic-length), the factor $c$ is not needed in this calculation. As answered in the comments, [here](http://www.bourbaphy.fr/doucotpasquier.pdf), the expression for the magnetic length is $\sqrt{\hbar / eB}$ (I just give up, and not thinking about the reduced Plank constant), without $c$.

Is it possible to understand why in first place a wrong unit is used in the measure of the degeneration in such a vaste number of sources? Why does the Hamiltonian is expressed with or without $c$?

I know that this may be entirely my fault, but I just don't understand.

Comment: This could be a matter of the system of units used (SI vs. cgs).

Comment: Indeed it is... Thank you very much, I'm just not used to those units.